# PHP Parsing error results from string variable containing a drive path

Tags: php

I'm getting an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

On the line with `$szSearchDBPath` below. It seems like PHP doesn't like something about the drive path.

I've spent hours Googling to try and find the problem, but with no success.

From my understanding, a single quoted string is not parsed and should be interpreted literally.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

```
<?php
$szHost = getcwd();
$szAddDir = "";
$g_bSaveSearch = 'True';
$szContentRoot = 'd:\websites\lycos\Alpha_Pourri\';
$szSearchDBPath = 'd:\websites\lycos\Alpha_Pourri\searches\';
$bPRODSite = 'False';
$i = 0;
...
```

Comment: Single quotes and backslashes *do* need to be escaped in a single-quoted string literal. However, no other characters do (in contrast to a double-quoted string literal). That's probably what caught you; see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: @Jon: Actually you don't even need to escape the backslash - unless it can be interpreted as an escaping backslash, i.e. if it is followed by a quote. PS: You can just use a normal slash on windows, too ;) no need to deal with backslashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since backslashes are used for escape characters, you're accidentally escaping the ending single quote by putting a backslash before it.  Try turning all your backslashes into double backslashes, eg

```
$szContentRoot = 'd:\\websites\\lycos\\Alpha_Pourri\\';
```

Comment: Dan, it looks like your answer was posted a second before the other two so I'll marks yours as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes are technically escape characters in PHP, so you must double escape them:

```
<?php
$szHost = getcwd();
$szAddDir = "";
$g_bSaveSearch = 'True';
$szContentRoot = 'd:\\websites\\lycos\\Alpha_Pourri\\';
$szSearchDBPath = 'd:\\websites\\lycos\\Alpha_Pourri\\searches\\';
$bPRODSite = 'False';
$i = 0;
```

For more information about this you can refer to the [manual entry about strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> To specify a literal single quote,
>   escape it with a backslash (). To
>   specify a literal backslash, double it
>   (\). ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$szContentRoot = 'd:\websites\lycos\Alpha_Pourri\';
```

The `\` escapes the single quote `'`, thus the string doesn't end there. Escape the backslash

```
$szContentRoot = 'd:\websites\lycos\Alpha_Pourri\\';
```

It should be sufficient to escape the last one (because its in single quotes). However, you may replace every `\` with `\\`. Or you just use the common forward slash `/`, because windows accept both as directory separator.

Comment: KingCrunch, thank you for the additional options of getting around this problem...

Comment: King, one other note:  I tried both your recommendations and they both work.  However, if a backslash is technically an escape character, it might be more "safe" to double backslash each instance, rather than the last one only.  But like I said, both worked for me.